# How to use OR in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and can't figure why this query returns no results BUT I do know it's becuase I'm using the OR condition incorrectly. If

Can someone please show the correct way to go about this?

```
SELECT trddata.id, trddata.ts, instr.name, instr.underlying, instr.expiration,instr.strike, instr.callput,opnint.vol, trdind.name ind,exch.name exch, trddata.price,trddata.bidprcbbo,trddata.askprcbbo  
FROM trdopt trddata 
JOIN instropt instr 
ON trddata.optid = instr.id 
JOIN trdindopt trdind 
ON trdind.id = trddata.ind 
JOIN exchopt exch 
ON trddata.exchcode = exch.id 
JOIN opnintopt opnint 
ON opnint.optid = trddata.optid 
WHERE opnint.ds = DATE_FORMAT(trddata.ts, '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND trddata.id >= 71125752 
AND trddata.ts <= '2013-06-20 16:30:36' 
AND instr.underlying = 'AAPL'  
AND exch.name = 'AMEX'  
OR exch.name = 'CBOE'  
OR exch.name = 'ISE'  
OR exch.name = 'PHLX'  
ORDER BY trddata.id 
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want some parenthesis :

```
AND (exch.name = 'AMEX'  
OR exch.name = 'CBOE'  
OR exch.name = 'ISE'  
OR exch.name = 'PHLX')
```

You could also use IN :

```
AND exch.name IN ('AMEX','CBOE','ISE','PHLX')
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use ()
For example

```
SELECT trddata.id, trddata.ts, instr.name, instr.underlying, instr.expiration,instr.strike, instr.callput,opnint.vol, trdind.name ind,exch.name exch, trddata.price,trddata.bidprcbbo,trddata.askprcbbo  
FROM trdopt trddata 
JOIN instropt instr 
ON trddata.optid = instr.id 
JOIN trdindopt trdind 
ON trdind.id = trddata.ind 
JOIN exchopt exch 
ON trddata.exchcode = exch.id 
JOIN opnintopt opnint 
ON opnint.optid = trddata.optid 
WHERE opnint.ds = DATE_FORMAT(trddata.ts, '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND trddata.id >= 71125752 
AND trddata.ts <= '2013-06-20 16:30:36' 
AND instr.underlying = 'AAPL'  
AND (exch.name = 'AMEX'  
OR exch.name = 'CBOE'  
OR exch.name = 'ISE'  
OR exch.name = 'PHLX')
ORDER BY trddata.id 
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query and verify if it is because of OR condition or not:

```
SELECT trddata.id, trddata.ts, instr.name, instr.underlying, instr.expiration,instr.strike, instr.callput,opnint.vol, trdind.name ind,exch.name exch, trddata.price,trddata.bidprcbbo,trddata.askprcbbo  
FROM trdopt trddata 
JOIN instropt instr 
ON trddata.optid = instr.id 
JOIN trdindopt trdind 
ON trdind.id = trddata.ind 
JOIN exchopt exch 
ON trddata.exchcode = exch.id 
JOIN opnintopt opnint 
ON opnint.optid = trddata.optid 
WHERE opnint.ds = DATE_FORMAT(trddata.ts, '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND trddata.id >= 71125752 
AND trddata.ts <= '2013-06-20 16:30:36' 
AND instr.underlying = 'AAPL'  
AND exch.name in ('AMEX' , 'CBOE', 'ISE','PHLX')
ORDER BY trddata.id 
LIMIT 100;
```